# Bootstrap 3 CSS Responsive Grid IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, grid, twitter-bootstrap-3

Been combing the code and searching google/stack/forums for a while, but no luck.  I've got a layout built with bootstrap 3 that uses should be 4 columns at lg, 3 at md, 2 at sm and 1 at sm.  It works on all browsers except ie8.  On ie8, only one column is shown as the col-xs-12 is overriding everything.  I have implemented the require.js script, the IE=Edge meta tag, and *think* I have the scripts loading in the correct order.  Below is the html/css/js.  Anyone catch anything that I didn't?

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6978014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in the require.js script somewhere.  Pulled down the latest minified version and it suddenly worked.  :P